# DeepEqual []interface{}

Tags: go, reflection, deepequals

Looking at the following golang code:

```
b := []byte(`["a", "b"]`)
var value interface{}
json.Unmarshal(b, &value)
fmt.Println(value)                 // Print [a b]
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value)) //Print []interface {}
var targetValue interface{} = []string{"a", "b"}
if reflect.DeepEqual(value.([]interface{}), targetValue) {
    t.Error("please be equal")
}
```

Am I expecting too much of `DeepEqual`? Reading the documentation, the following statements reinforce my assumption that it should work:

- Array values are deeply equal when their corresponding elements are deeply equal.
- Interface values are deeply equal if they hold deeply equal concrete values.
- Slice values are deeply equal when (...) or their corresponding elements (up to length) are deeply equal.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You may find these interesting. [Package for equality of Go values: google/go-cmp](https://github.com/google/go-cmp). [Life of a Go Infrastructure Maintainer](https://medium.com/@zombiezen/life-of-a-go-infrastructure-maintainer-cb1419308eb5).

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing a `[]interface{}` against `[]string`, which should never be equal.

```
if reflect.DeepEqual(value.([]interface{}), targetValue) {
```

compared against `targetValue` which is of type `[]string`:

```
var targetValue interface{} = []string{"a", "c"}
```

Comment: Understood. I assumed they would both be interfaces, or both []string. I guess this would fall under "Values of distinct types are never deeply equal.".
What can I do to make them of the same type to I can compare?

Comment: Got it! Instead of declaring my targetValue with literal values, I use `append()`. Doing this preserves the `[]interface{}` type.

Comment: The easy way in your specific case would be:
`var targetValue interface{} = []interface{}{"a", "b"}`

Comment: Indeed that's even better. Can you update your answer?

Comment: yeap, as @Flimzy mentioned, if you declare it as []interface{}, then the types would be same and hence, reflect would deep equal should give out true - https://play.golang.org/p/iN3STrExW64

Comment: @Flimzy can you update your answer with your suggestion, so the answer will be complete?